# Can anyone explain these differences between two similar i7 processors?

Tags: performance, central-processing-unit

I have two systems I've just built. They both have i7 processors and Asus P8Z77 motherboards. When I run a simple processor loop benchmark that I wrote in Delphi some time back I get one machine showing nealry twice as fast as the other. I then used CPU-Z to dump me the details of the hardware and I see that the fast machine shows:

```
Processor 1                     ID = 0
        Number of cores         4 (max 8)
        Number of threads       8 (max 16)
        Name                    Intel Core i7 2700K
        Codename                Sandy Bridge
        Specification           Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2700K CPU @ 3.50GHz
        Package (platform ID)   Socket 1155 LGA (0x1)
        CPUID                   6.A.7
        Extended CPUID          6.2A
        Core Stepping           D2
        Technology              32 nm
        TDP Limit               95 Watts
        Core Speed              3610.7 MHz
        Multiplier x FSB        36.0 x 100.3 MHz
        Stock frequency         3500 MHz
```

the slow machine shows:

```
Processor 1                     ID = 0
        Number of cores         4 (max 8)
        Number of threads       8 (max 16)
        Name                    Intel Core i7 2600K
        Codename                Sandy Bridge
        Specification           Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2600K CPU @ 3.40GHz
        Package (platform ID)   Socket 1155 LGA (0x1)
        CPUID                   6.A.7
        Extended CPUID          6.2A
        Core Stepping           D2
        Technology              32 nm
        TDP Limit               95 Watts
        Core Speed              1648.2 MHz
        Multiplier x FSB        16.0 x 103.0 MHz
        Stock frequency         3400 MHz
```

i.e the slow machine has a 2600k to the fast machine 2700k. The very different "Multiplier x FSB" must be significant but I dont understand how two processors with a very 'similar' number can be so different. To get the machines the same must I copy the processors or is there some clever setting that I can change?

Thanks for any help.
Brian.

Comment: Your benchmark is probably too simple to show anything useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your processor `Core Speed` scales up and down based on usage (to save power, amongst other things). `Multiplier x FSB = Core Speed` so that'll change on the 2600k machine once it gets busy.

You can, if you really want, change your [scaling governors](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CPU_Frequency_Scaling#Scaling_governors) to `performance`, if you want your `Core Speed` to always be the maximum it can ever be.

Comment: Note that there's no reason you should do this and no reason you should want to do this.

Comment: Great, thanks. I see now that the difference turned out to be cooling policy setting affecting clock multiplier. Thanks.